# Apache drill Error Index out of bounds

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-drill

Im performing queries with apache drill over a 100GB dataset in relatively small cluster (4 nodes with 16GB). When i try to run a certain query it gives me the following error:

> Error: SYSTEM ERROR: IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 88, length: 4
>   (expected: range(0, 64)).

Im using the standard TPCH-H data model, the error happens in Query 12.The same query ran successfully when i was working with a smaller dataset. Can someone give some sugestion why this happens?

Query:

```
select
    l_shipmode,
    sum(case
        when o_orderpriority = '1-URGENT'
            or o_orderpriority = '2-HIGH'
            then 1
        else 0
    end) as high_line_count,
    sum(case
        when o_orderpriority <> '1-URGENT'
            and o_orderpriority <> '2-HIGH'
            then 1
        else 0
    end) as low_line_count
from
    pq_orders,
    pq_lineitem
where
    o_orderkey = l_orderkey
    and l_shipmode in ('REG AIR', 'MAIL')
    and l_commitdate < l_receiptdate
    and l_shipdate < l_commitdate
    and l_receiptdate >= '1995-01-01'
    and l_receiptdate < '1996-01-01'
group by
    l_shipmode
order by
    l_shipmode;
```

Comment: Add the query and the table(s) definition

Comment: Im using the standard TPC-H dataset, running Query 12, Ill update the question with the query

Comment: what is the drill version? There seems to be some relevant bugs in earlier versions.

Comment: the version is 1.10.0, if im not mistaken in the lastest version

Comment: I think this is due to the config parameter set in drill UI. Change memory per node and memory per query to lesser value and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace of the error?